# Simple Dom Html send session

Tags: php, html, dom, cookies, file-get-contents

I just want to use "file_get_html" to get content of specific pages, but this content just avaiable for loggin user, is there any way to send cookie to let target site know that the page is accessed by logged in user.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$opts = array("Cookie: __qca=P0-1170249003-1395413811270"); //__qca=P0-1170249003-1395413811270

$current_url = 'http://abc.xyz';
// But it will be redirect to
$url = 'http://www.blogger.com/blogin.g?blogspotURL=http://abc.xyz'
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_html($url, FALSE, $context);
echo $html;
```

I do something like this, but it doesn't work.
How Can I do this with Curl?
Thanks.

Comment: Anyway to do this without curl. I'm using the file_get_html method. But I do echo I see the page as if I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ch = curl_init(); // your curl instance

curl_setopt_array($ch, [CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.blogger.com/blogin.g?blogspotURL=http://abc.xyz", CURLOPT_COOKIE => "__qca=P0-1170249003-1395413811270"], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]);

$result = curl_exec($ch); // request's result

$html = new simple_html_dom(); // create new parser instance
$html->load($result); // load and parse previous result
```

In this example I used [`curl_setopt_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) to set the various CURL parameters instead of calling [`curl_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) for each one of them.

`CURLOPT_URL` sets the target URL, `CURLOPT_COOKIE` sets the cookies to send, if there are multiple cookies then they must be separated with a semicolon followed by a space, finally the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` tells CURL to return the server's response as a string.

`curl_exec()` executes the request and returns its result.

Then we create an instance of `simple_html_dom` and load that previous result into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @andre, I spent all evening yesterday to find the solution :
The first we make curl exe to login to google account.
and save cookie to a text file (exam : "/tmp/cookie.txt")
and the next time everything we have to do is only take cookie content in this file to get remote content.

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Construct an HTTP POST request
$clientlogin_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$clientlogin_post = array(
    "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
    "Email" => "youracc@gmail.com",
    "Passwd" => "yourpasswd",
    "service" => "blogger",
    "source" => "your application name"
);

// Initialize the curl object
$curl = curl_init($clientlogin_url);

// Set some options (some for SHTTP)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clientlogin_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");

// Execute
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;

// Get the Auth string and save it
preg_match("/Auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
$auth = $matches[1];

echo "The auth string is: " . $auth;
// Include the Auth string in the headers
// Together with the API version being used
$headers = array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $auth,
    "GData-Version: 3.0",
);


$url = 'http://testlink.html';
$curl = curl_init();
// Make the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = new simple_html_dom(); // Create new parser instance
$html->load($response);

foreach($html->find('img') as $img) {
  //echo $img->src . '</br>';
}
```